# error with intent android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

my mainactivity.java looks now like this :

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class FirstTabFragment extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
    final View button = v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onlogin(v);
        }
    });
    return v;
}

public void onlogin(View button) {
    final Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, user.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}


    }
```

and my application is still crushing when i click on the button :S

LogCat :

04-30 20:18:50.520: E/AndroidRuntime(17203): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 20:18:50.520: E/AndroidRuntime(17203): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
04-30 20:18:50.520: E/AndroidRuntime(17203):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1095)
04-30 20:18:50.520: E/AndroidRuntime(17203):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:276)
04-30 20:18:50.520: E/AndroidRuntime(17203):    at com.example.bloodneeded.FirstTabFragment.onlogin(FirstTabFragment.java:37)
04-30 20:18:50.520: E/AndroidRuntime(17203):    at com.example.bloodneeded.FirstTabFragment$1.onClick(FirstTabFragment.java:28)
04-30 20:18:50.520: E/AndroidRuntime(17203):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
04-30 20:18:50.520: E/AndroidRuntime(17203):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14400)
04-30 20:18:50.520: E/AndroidRuntime(17203):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-30 20:18:50.520: E/AndroidRuntime(17203):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-30 20:18:50.520: E/AndroidRuntime(17203):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
04-30 20:18:50.520: E/AndroidRuntime(17203):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
04-30 20:18:50.520: E/AndroidRuntime(17203):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 20:18:50.520: E/AndroidRuntime(17203):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-30 20:18:50.520: E/AndroidRuntime(17203):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-30 20:18:50.520: E/AndroidRuntime(17203):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-30 20:18:50.520: E/AndroidRuntime(17203):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't get the point what "this" really means. The setClass takes two paremeters - the Context and the Class. If you do this in an Activity, you specify "this" because the Activity extends Context (another words, and Activity is a Context). The Fragment is not a Context so you get this error. The Context can also be obtained in a different way.
The startActivity method is also a Context method.
And also it is less code to set the ComponentName from the constructor if an intent.

```
public void onlogin(View button) {
    final Context context = getActvity();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, user.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Don't name classes with lower case letters. The class names should start with upper case letter. It's not an error, but rather a convention.

And about the getView method

```
return (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container,false);
```

There is absolutely no need to cast this to a Relativelayout. Just return the

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container,false);
```

About

```
if (container == null) {
    return null;
}
```

Not sure what it means, but mostly

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
}
```

must be fine

Also it crashes because

```
public void onlogin(View button) {
    final Context context = getActvity();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, user.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Must be defined in the context to which this View is attached.

This means that in order to work it must be defined in the Activity, not in Fragment.
You have two ways of solving this
1) put this method in your Activity

2) If you want to define it in the Fragment, you should remove

```
android:onclick
```

from xml, set the button id

```
android:id="@+id/yourButtonId"
```

and set the onClickListener directly on the button.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
    final View button = v.findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onlogin(v);
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Can u plz check my edit question to see the logcat errors ? cz i did like u said but when i click on the button the application crashed

Comment: Updated the answer with the fix.

Comment: plz check the new edited question , cause my app is still crushing man

Comment: Did you set the onClickListener on the button and removed the android:onClick from xml as I suggested (the bottom of the answer)?

Comment: sry man for taking from ur time :S but am still beginner in abdroid development and i am getting lost everywhere :p thank you for your replies , you are really helping me

Comment: If you removed android:onclick from xml and still getting this error (java.lang.NoSuchMethodException) it could be that you did not removed it everywhere, if you are sure you did, then click project - clean in eclipse menu. It sometimes refreshes the xml badly.

Comment: btw when i copied ur code , i get an error under (new View.onClickListener() so i changed it to (new OnClickListener() u think thats the problem ?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it on the fly. It should have started with an uppercase letter, so it should have been "new View.OnClickListener()", but "new OnClickListener()" is also fine, if you import it correctly.

Comment: And sorry, I was wrong about the getApplicationContext(). When I saw your error, I remembered why. It can be used with the flag, but it is much simpler just to use the Activity Context. Use the onlogin() method from the edited answer.

Comment: ouff man , u made my big day ... i am really thankful to u .. reallly really tahnk u

Answer (score 2):

As you are in the Fragment, you should `getActivity()` instead of `this`
Try this

```
 intent.setClass(getActivity(), user.class);
```

**Edit:**
      also include this

```
  getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Not a full answer. context.startActivity(intent) is needed to be mentioned also.

Comment: man the error disappeared but when i click on button the application crashed .. can u check my edited question in order to see what is the logcat ? :s

Comment: @Charbel Post your logcat trace.. or part of it..And also try my edit

Comment: "getActivity().getContext()" wrong again. getActivity().startActivity(intent) is fine.

Comment: @DoctororDrive it is `getActivity()` only , I have forgot to remove getcontent(), first i Have get the context from button and then I have edited this.

Comment: @Charbel I think, your problem is solved as you have mark DoctorDrive post as answer..

Answer (score 0):

try 
   intent.setClass(FirstTabFragment.this, user.class);